# Lexicographic preference relation not continuous

Tags: microeconomics, preferences

I’m having trouble understanding why lexicographic preference relations aren’t continuous. I need inspiration on how this proof would work.

Comment: https://economics.stackexchange.com/search?q=lexicographic

Answer (score 3):

**Definition**: $\succsim$ on $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ is said to be continuous if

for any two convergent sequences $(x'_n,y'_n), (x''_n,y''_n) \in \mathbb{R}^2_+$,

$(x'_n,y'_n)\succsim (x''_n,y''_n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

implies

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (x'_n,y'_n)\succsim \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (x''_n,y''_n)$

**Definition:** Lexicographic preference relation $\succsim$ on $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ is defined as follows:

for any $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2_+$,

$(x_1,y_1)\succsim (x_2,y_2)$
**if and only if**
either $x_1 > x_2$ or $(x_1 = x_2 \text{ and } y_1\geq y_2)$

**Claim.** Lexicographic preference relation $\succsim$ on $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ is not continuous.

**Proof.** Consider the following two sequences:

$(x'_n,y'_n) = \left(1+\frac{1}{n},0\right)$

and a constant sequence

$(x''_n,y''_n) = (1,1)$

Observe that $(x'_n,y'_n)\succsim (x''_n,y''_n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ holds, but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (x'_n,y'_n) = (1,0) \not\succsim (1,1)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (x''_n,y''_n)$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For example for the lexicographix preferences on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$take any ball around $(1,1)$. Although you know that $(1,1) \succ (1,0)$, there exist points in the given ball ($(1-\epsilon,1)$) such that $(1,0)\succ (1-\epsilon,1)$ which contradicts with the definition of continuity. I hope this helps!